# Getting mount Error "Not a data message"

Tags: terminal, mount, android

I'm trying to mount a 2bd partition on my MicrSD Card in Termux (A terminal app on Android)on my Android device. I have been doing this for a long time without any problems. Now recently when I try to mount I get a message "Not a data message". I can't find any information on this error message. I have searched the web but only found references to this error but not any detail on what causes it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I tried mounting in terminal in TWRP recovery as well with the same message.

Thank You,
Sruly

Answer (score 0):

it seems that this error means the partition is corrupted. After fixing the partition table I was able to mount.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever comes here because they get "Not a data message" for single files, e.g. during installation or backups in TWRP:
Those files somehow got corrupted (by a failed Magisk install in my case).

To fix it: Boot to TWRP, adb in, umount respective partitions with the erroneous files and use `e2fsck -f <partition>` to fix them.

If you need a list of corrupted files (potentially because they need to be recreated somehow, either by reinstalling an app, flashing the OS, restoring from a backup), use the following:

```
sed -n "/Not a data message/s#.*: '\([^']*\)'.*#\1#p" /tmp/recovery.log | sort -u >/tmp/missing_files.txt
```

Comment: (1) You don’t need to use a delimiter other than `/` just because the *data* might contain `/` characters; only if your *old* string (the regex) or your *new* string (the replacement) contains `/` characters. (2) Filenames that contain newline are a lost cause (unless they are somehow sanitized in the log file), but what about filenames that contain apostrophe, or the string `: '`?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica'
ad 1: Who said I would? :-) Good admins are lazy. I replace paths more often than I do comments or other stuff containing hashes. I always use s###, also find it easier to read, 'cause they stand out.
ad 2: They don't. At least not on my Android. I saw the list, confirmed the pattern worked. But yeah, we can play a game of regex golf!
(Whoever puts newlines,`'`, `: '` or other fuckery in their filenames deserves to not get their files fixed)
PS: I should have added `rm -rf /` after the actual command to make it clear people still have to think for themselves ;-)